# How can I install package lsq-ellipse for Anaconda?

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I would like to install the package [lsq-ellipse](https://pypi.org/project/lsq-ellipse/) to use in Anaconda.

`pip install lsq-ellipse` executes in Anaconda Powershell Prompt, but `import ellipses` does not work in my Jupyter notebook after the pip installation.

`conda install lsq-ellipse` fails in Anaconda Powershell Prompt with a PackagesNotFoundError.

Please advise how to install this package for Anaconda.

Comment: When you want to install packages so that you can use them in your notebook, you need to make sure that the package is installed into the interpreter that runs the notebook kernel. The easiest way to ensure that is to run `%pip install lsq-ellipse` directly inside a notebook cell. (%conda and %mamba also works!)

Comment: @cel Thanks for the suggestion. "%pip install lsq-ellipse" executed in the notebook, but "import ellipses" yielded a ModuleNotFoundError.